# Debugging FireFox for stored credentials

Tags: http, automation, firefox-addon, basic-authentication

To implement automatic log-in on server's 401 Query ( Basic Authentication) i am using **nsHttpAuthManager**( a manager that stored credentials to bre used in automatic authenticat). when i am adding the credentials it should be added to HTTP authentication manager but for some reason popup for credential is still coming.How can i check what are the values of a stored entry
 how can i test whether Credentials with port,username,password,realm are being added to Authentication manager or not? Any tutorial would help.

Comment: Is XPCOM still used for language-agnostic addons development in the Latest FireFox version? i doubt as it is not loaded in th FireFox process.

Comment: Yes XPCOM is used, they are not loaded in e10s processes unless requested, and addons can make that request.

Comment: how would you know if your ff browser is e10s process of not ... i tried to see this in my ff preference but dint find any option to enable/disable e10s. i m using 38.0.5 FF browser is it e10s ? FYI my browser is not loading xpcom. How do be request browser to load xpcom?

Comment: It's only enabled in Firefox 40 right now I think. 38 is release channel you dont have it, if you go to options page you'll see there may be an option to enable it.

Comment: Do you mean, xpcom should be loaded by default in ff(firefox) 38.0.5 ? as i mentioned earlier, I check the optoin/preference page of my FF but dint find any option to enable/disable e10s( i guess the reason is 38.0.5 is release channel). could you suggest me a read on this topic please.

Comment: On 38 then you don't have e10s, so then xpcom is loaded by default in everything.